# Validate from a subset of rules in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have a model that in one field, can store a number for different purposes as user chooses a type of parameter (money, number, age, tag id, etc). So, I would like to validate it, and in the model I should put all the rules that this field can have. But since it depends of the parameter type, it should validate it according to the type specified (e.g. money no less than 1000, age between 18 and 65, etc). Is there a way to choose a subset of rules and validate over that?

Comment: you should make custom validation rules and pass in the callbackfunction whatever parameters you need

Comment: So no way of doing with cake's own functionality? Sigh...anyway, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can override the model validation rules on the fly in your controller before you do your validation. So for your example, you could do something like this:

in Controller:

```
switch ($type) {

   case "a":

       $this->Model->validate = array(
           // validation rules for case A 
       );

       break;

    case "b":

       $this->Model->validate = array(
           // validation rules for case B 
       );

       break;

    // etc

}
```

Alternatively (and better IMHO):

Setup your alternative validation rules in the model:

```
public $validateCaseA = array(
    // validation rules for case A
);

public $valdayeCaseB = array(
    // validation rules for case B
);
```

and in your controller:

```
switch ($type) {

   case "a":

       $this->Model->validate = $this->Model->validateCaseA;

       break;

    case "b":

       $this->Model->validate = $this->Model->validateCaseB;

       break;

    // etc

}
```

or alternatively...

in Model:

```
public $validateCase = array(
    'a'=>array(
        // validation rules for case A
    ),
    'b'=>array(
        // validation rules for case A
    )
    //etc
);
```

in Controller:

```
$this->Model->validate = $this->Model->validateCase($type);
```

If your case rules have common validation rules, you can use array_merge_recursive to cut down on duplication between the rule sets:

in Model:

```
public $commonValidation = array(
   //common validation rules
);
```

in Controller:

```
$this->Model->validate = array_merge_recursive($this->Model->commonValidation, $this->Model->validateCase($type));
```